# Is there a way to pump fully formatted string/text through an empty variable in python?

Tags: python, string, variables, formatted

I'm a little new to python and I'm trying to fill raw_input with a formatted string yet my output never changes the "\n" character and always returns null. Is there a way to pump fully formatted string/text through an empty variable?

```
text = ""
stop = "|"


while True:
   text_1 = raw_input()
   text += "%s" % (text1)
   if text_1 != stop:
     pass
   else:
     break


print text

output:
hello world
how are you
|
hello worldhow are you|
```

need: 
hello world
how are you
|

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused at what you mean by "fully formatted text". I'm also confused at what you mean by "returns null".

`raw_input` returns the string that was read, which might be an empty string, but should never be `None`. By the way, if you are familiar with `NULL` in C-like languages, `None` is sort of the equivalent in Python.

This piece of code is close to yours and has what I believe is your desired behavior.

```python
text = ""
stop = "|"


while True:
  text_1 = raw_input()
  if text_1 != stop:
    text += text_1 + " "
  else:
    text += text_1
    break

print text
```